# In listview adapter replace image on click of that image

Tags: android, adapter

I have to change image on click of that image.whan I am trying to do that it is changing image but not at that position,at a random position.
Code

```
     public class InteractiveArrayAdapter extends
    ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> {
public boolean[] checkBoxState;
boolean[] favStar;
ViewHolder viewholder;
// private Object inflater;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems;

public InteractiveArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems) {
    super(context, resource, menuItems);
    this.menuItems = menuItems;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    checkBoxState = new boolean[menuItems.size()];
}

private class ViewHolder {
    // ImageView photo;
    TextView title, link, published, description;
    // ImageButton newsCheck;
    public ImageView newsCheck;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        // inflater =
        // LayoutInflater.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item1, null);
        viewholder = new ViewHolder();

        // cache the views
        // viewholder.photo=(ImageView)
        // convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo);
        viewholder.title = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.news_title);
        // viewholder.link = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.link);
        viewholder.published = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.published);
        viewholder.description = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.description);
        viewholder.newsCheck = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.newsCheck);
        System.out.println("position" + position);

        // link the cached views to the convertview
        convertView.setTag(viewholder);

    } else
        viewholder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    HashMap<String, String> catalog_list = new HashMap<String, String>();
    catalog_list = menuItems.get(position);

    // viewholder.link.setText(catalog_list.get("NEWS_KEY_LINK")
    //
    // viewholder.link.setText(catalog_list
    // .get(NewsXMLParsingActivity.NEWS_KEY_LINK));
    viewholder.title.setText(catalog_list
            .get(NewsXMLParsingActivity.NEWS_KEY_TITLE));
    viewholder.published.setText(catalog_list
            .get(NewsXMLParsingActivity.NEWS_KEY_PUB));
    viewholder.description.setText(catalog_list
            .get(NewsXMLParsingActivity.NEWS_KEY_DESCRIPTION));
    viewholder.newsCheck.setTag(position);
    viewholder.newsCheck.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            viewholder.newsCheck.getTag(position);
            System.out.println(v.getTag() + "qqqqqq");
            int position = (Integer) v.getTag(); // This will retrieve your
                                                    // clicked image

            viewholder.newsCheck.setImageResource(R.drawable.favv2);

        }
    });

    return convertView;

}
```

}

Comment: @MurtazaHussain I didn't got it how to use it?

Comment: @poojagupta first remove the global declaration of `ViewHolder`... There is a problem with that. It will be overriden with new one every time `getView()` is called...

Comment: @Gopal Rao it is not working

Comment: @poojagupta You need to maintain the positions `ImageView`s in an `ArrayList` whose image is changed. then in `getView()` method, if position is in that Arraylist, set the image resource to `R.drwable.favv2` or to old one...

Comment: @GopalRao could you please give me programming example

Comment: @poojagupta initially which image will ImageView contains? I mean before click, which image resource you are using. I will try to post answer...

Comment: @GopalRao favv1 name image it will contain and on click it will change to favv2(for bookmarking I am using)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this...

```
public class InteractiveArrayAdapter extends
        ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> {
    public boolean[] checkBoxState;
    boolean[] favStar;
    // private Object inflater;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems;
    // track the positions of images changed;
    private final HashSet<Integer> imageIndexes;

    public InteractiveArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems) {
        super(context, resource, menuItems);
        this.menuItems = menuItems;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        checkBoxState = new boolean[menuItems.size()];
        imageIndexes = new HashSet<Integer>();
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        // ImageView photo;
        TextView title, link, published, description;
        // ImageButton newsCheck;
        public ImageView newsCheck;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewholder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // inflater =
            // LayoutInflater.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item1, null);
            viewholder = new ViewHolder();

            // cache the views
            // viewholder.photo=(ImageView)
            // convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo);
            viewholder.title = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.news_title);
            // viewholder.link = (TextView)
            // convertView.findViewById(R.id.link);
            viewholder.published = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.published);
            viewholder.description = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.description);
            viewholder.newsCheck = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.newsCheck);
            System.out.println("position" + position);

            // link the cached views to the convertview
            convertView.setTag(viewholder);

        } else {
            viewholder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        HashMap<String, String> catalog_list = new HashMap<String, String>();
        catalog_list = menuItems.get(position);

        // viewholder.link.setText(catalog_list.get("NEWS_KEY_LINK")
        //
        // viewholder.link.setText(catalog_list
        // .get(NewsXMLParsingActivity.NEWS_KEY_LINK));
        viewholder.title.setText(catalog_list
                .get(NewsXMLParsingActivity.NEWS_KEY_TITLE));
        viewholder.published.setText(catalog_list
                .get(NewsXMLParsingActivity.NEWS_KEY_PUB));
        viewholder.description.setText(catalog_list
                .get(NewsXMLParsingActivity.NEWS_KEY_DESCRIPTION));
        viewholder.newsCheck.setTag(position);
        if(imageIndexes.contains(Integer.valueOf(position))) {
            viewholder.newsCheck.setImageResource(R.drawable.favv2);
        } else {
            viewholder.newsCheck.setImageResource(R.drawable.favv1);
        }
        viewholder.newsCheck.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = (Integer) v.getTag(); 
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v;
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.favv2);
                imageIndexes.add(Integer.valueOf(position));
            }
        });

        return convertView;

    }
}
```

Comment: it is not working only favv2 image is coming when it got loaded and on click no change is visible

Comment: @poojagupta sorry. a little typo mistake at `viewholder.newsCheck.setImageResource(R.drawable.favv2);` and `viewholder.newsCheck.setImageResource(R.drawable.favv1);`. please once again try my edited answer...

Comment: @MikeM. definitely I would suggest if that is a case for OP needs.

Answer (score 3):

When you click on the `ImageView`, the `View v` parameter will be the `ImageView` itself. So, if all you need to do is change the Image, you merely need to cast this as an `ImageView`, and change its Image Resource.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    ((ImageView) v).setImageResource(R.drawable.favv2);
}
```

Comment: M.still it is changing image but randomly

Comment: Ah, I think I know what you mean. Yes, as @GopalRao says in his comment, you need to keep track of the ImageViews you've changed.

Comment: how to keep track of imageview