# View holder OnClickListener event issue

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-adapter

I am creating a listview adapter with view holder :

```
final ViewHolder holder;
if (convertView == null) {
     convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list_layout, null);
     holder = new ViewHolder();
     //Layout Code here
     convertView.setTag(holder);
}
else {
     holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
```

setting Onclick Listener :

```
 holder.view.setOnClickListener(titleListener);
 final OnClickListener titleListener = new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
          holder.view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.top_bar);
          notifyDataSetChanged();

          }
     };
```

Inside the Onclick listner, I change the background image of selected view.   But here, with the selected item, for other items in the same listview, the background image is getting changed.  Please suggest me what modifications I need to make to change BG for only the selected item.

Updated code for getview :

```
final ViewHolder holder;        

if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.activity_news_list_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
            holder.view = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tView);
            holder.opacityView = (View) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.opacity_view);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

holder.view.setOnClickListener(titleListener);
 final OnClickListener titleListener = new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
          holder.view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.top_bar);
          notifyDataSetChanged();

          }
     };

 holder.view.setOnClickListener(titleListener);
        return convertView;
```

Please check the image, I selected the row "This Dubai Community", but background changed for "I was Confident" also. There are some other rows too which was selected on the click event

[image]

Comment: plz, show all code in getView()

Comment: I think your problem is similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317700/in-listview-adapter-replace-image-on-click-of-that-image#22317852)...

Comment: Can you just try to set background like this `v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.top_bar);` even you have to code more to manage views.

Comment: @GopalRao Tried but same result :(

Comment: Why are you setting an `onClickListener` inside your adapter? If the adapter is being applied to a `ListView` shouldn't you be handling the event in the `ListView`'s `setOnItemClickListener`?

Comment: Better you use drawable selector to accommodate this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
holder.view.setOnClickListener(titleListener);
final OnClickListener titleListener = new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
      Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.newImage); //new Image 
      holder.view..setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
      notifyDataSetChanged();

      }
 };
```

Comment: This is not valid Java: `holder.view..setBackgroundDrawable`

Comment: Directly modifying a ViewHolder like this in a click handler is a bad idea, especially when you then immediately call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.  You need to update the data and then notify the adapter to make the change.

Answer (score 0):

```
Relativelayout rlayout=holder.view;
```

please add above line ...

```
holder.view.setOnClickListener(titleListener);
 final OnClickListener titleListener = new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
          rlayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.top_bar);
          notifyDataSetChanged();

          }
     };
```

Comment: Directly modifying a ViewHolder like this in a click handler is a bad idea, especially when you then immediately call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.  You need to update the data and then notify the adapter to make the change.

Answer (score 0):

Use selector to select any row on click:

list_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:drawable="@color/android:on_press" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/android:activated_drawble" android:state_activated="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/android:normal_drawble"/>
```

Create this xml and apply in background of list row.

Then apply setActivated(true) to that holder view when it is clicked. That is it. This is right way to implement selector.

Comment: Directly modifying a ViewHolder like this in a click handler is a bad idea.  You need to update the data and then notify the adapter to make the change.